# How do I write exceptions to a text file? (JAVA)

Tags: java, exception, io

I am supposed to Use Scanner to read int values from a file “input.txt”, Read until end of file is reached, Write all program output to a file “output.txt”, Write all exceptions to a file “error.txt”, and Output each number read.

I understand exceptions for the most part, but I do not understand how to write all exceptions to a text file in Java...

Comment: Write a `try ... catch` block where you write the exception to `File error.txt` using `Printwriter`. More about `Printwriter` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java

Comment: Oh, I did not even think of it that way! Thank you!

Comment: I explained with more detail below. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Like I wrote in my comment, write a `try ... catch` block where you write the exception to `File` error.txt using `Printwriter`. 
For instance:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("error.txt");

try {

//Code to try goes here

} catch (Exception e) {

//You've got an exception. Now print it to error.txt
    writer.write(e.toString());

}
```

You could test with something simple like:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("error.txt");
int[] i = new int[1];
try {
    i[10] = 2;
} catch (Exception e) {
    writer.write(e.toString());
}
```

This results in error.txt being populated with:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

You can print the entire `Stack Trace` by doing

```
e.printStackTrace(writer);
```

**Very important** that you don't forget to close the `PrintWriter` or your file won't get printed to. Once you are done writing to the file, close with:

```
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

> use log4j for logging purpose,
>
> Also , configure it at Error level for printing error into different
>   file.
>
> from your java code, write below line will print whole stack-track to
>   the log file.

```
commons-logging, it's use likewise:

log.error("Message", exception);
```

Answer (score 0):

All exceptions have a method: `getMessage()` that will return the exception as a string. In addition, `toString()`, which all Java classes should have, gives a little bit more information, since it also calls `getMessage()`.